# Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree after change of planning frame

Tags: moveit, robotic-arm

I am trying to move the robotic arm by 1 cm from it's current value  using following code , when I use planning frame as top I am getting an error while when I use it as world it plans and execute successfully. I am also attaching robot_macro.xacro

I am pretty sure that there is no collision happening but feels like something is wrong with the transformation. Explanation of desired result -  I want to use aruco on a board above the ground names as "top" and use that as frame of reference to move the arm

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy import sys import moveit_commander from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseStamped

def move_arm():
    rospy.init_node('move_arm_node', anonymous=True)
    
    # Initialize MoveIt
    moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    group_name = "arm6"  # specify the name of your arm planning group
    move_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)

    # Get the current pose
    current_pose = move_group.get_current_pose().pose
    rospy.loginfo("Current Pose: \n{}".format(current_pose))
    
    # Calculate the desired pose
    desired_pose = Pose()
    desired_pose.position.x = current_pose.position.x   # Move 1 cm in the X direction
    desired_pose.position.y = current_pose.position.y - 0.001
    desired_pose.position.z = current_pose.position.z
    desired_pose.orientation = current_pose.orientation  # Maintain the same orientation
    
    # Set the target pose
    target_pose = PoseStamped()
    target_pose.header.frame_id = "top_plate"  # specify your planning frame
    target_pose.pose = desired_pose

    # Set the target pose for the end-effector
    move_group.set_pose_target(target_pose)
    
    # Plan and execute the trajectory
    move_group.go(wait=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        move_arm()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

**xacro**

```
<link name="top">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.78899 0.60325 0.025652"/> <!-- Size of the wall representation -->
    </geometry>
    <material name="Grey">
            <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
    </material>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/> 
  </visual>

    <!-- Adding collision geometry -->
  <collision>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.78899 0.60325 0.025652"/> <!-- Same size as visual representation -->
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>


<joint name="top" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="top" />
    <origin xyz="0 0.1778 0.554019" rpy="0 0 0" />
</joint>
```